# Django template rendering to itself

Tags: django-templates

I am trying to render the dictionary content using Django template like this
for example : result contain dictionary X

```
X={a:1,  
   b:1,  
   c:X(dictionary X again)  
   }
```

This could be any many places and at multiple levels

template : results.html, says something like following

```
{{a}}  
{{b}}  
{% if X.a %}
  {% include results.html %}  
{% endif %}
```

I thought that this would work but I get error saying

```
maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

How could I resolve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get rid of the c:X part in your dictionary X, you can't do that.

You can use X or properties included in it twice in your template, so there's no need for nested self-references in your dictionary.

Comment: I am sorry, I didnot get what you said
Are you saying not to render c:X?? well thats part of my program, I need that

Comment: you're nesting a dictionary in itself while creating it. It is something like : dict = { a:1, b:2, dict }. The second dict is either empty or you get a complaint about nesting too deep, depending on the situation. Also it adds no new data, your just repeating the whole dictionary. 
Either that or I am completing missing the point.